# How Many Standard Attack Modifier Cards?

Tags: gloomhaven

I am trying to verify that most or everything came in a Gloomhaven box. However, the rule book has its count for Attack Modifier Cards at 457. I was disconcerted to see I only had 145, until I realized each class has its own stash. I don't love the idea of opening every class, counting everything, and summing them up. What is the correct number of standard cards not specific to any class?

Comment: As a newcomer to Gloomhaven, I suggest you familiarize yourself with the [FAQ](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1897763/official-faq-game-no-rules-questions-please). See also [The Gloomhaven Rules Quiz](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/234575/gloomhaven-rules-quiz) for both the quiz itself, but also the "Basic Monster AI Questions" PDF. Finally, [this app](http://esotericsoftware.com/gloomhaven-helper) saves soooo much time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

145

- 4 base decks of 20 cards for players.
- 1 base deck of 20 cards for monsters.
- 10 Bless cards.
- 10 Curse cards for players.
- 10 Curse cards for monsters.
- 15 -1 cards for players.

Each base decks consists of the following cards:

- 1 x2
- 1 x0
- 1 +2
- 5 +1
- 6 +0
- 5 -1
- 1 -2

The 1st printing didn't have separate Curse cards for players and monsters. I don't know if the total count was the same or not.

---

The following are the class-specific Attack Modifier cards (including Forgotten Circle):

- 6 BRU:+1 cards
- 1 BRU:+1,Shield1S card
- 1 BRU:+3 card
- 1 BRU:r:DISARM card
- 1 BRU:r:MUDDLE card
- 2 BRU:r:PIERCE3 cards
- 6 BRU:r:PUSH1 cards
- 2 BRU:r:STUN cards
- 2 BRU:r:TARGET cards

- 1 TIN:+0 card
- 1 TIN:+0,TARGET card
- 2 TIN:+1 cards
- 2 TIN:+1,Heal2S cards
- 2 TIN:+1,IMMOBILIZE cards
- 2 TIN:+1,WOUND cards
- 1 TIN:+3 card
- 2 TIN:r:FIRE cards
- 3 TIN:r:MUDDLE cards

- 1 SPE:+0,STUN card
- 6 SPE:+1 cards
- 1 SPE:+1,CURSE card
- 1 SPE:+1,IMMOBILIZE card
- 1 SPE:+1,WOUND card
- 2 SPE:+2,FIRE cards
- 2 SPE:+2,ICE cards
- 1 SPE:r:AIR card
- 1 SPE:r:DARK card
- 1 SPE:r:EARTH card
- 1 SPE:r:LIGHT card

- 1 SCO:+0 card
- 1 SCO:+1 card
- 2 SCO:+2 cards
- 4 SCO:r:+1 cards
- 1 SCO:r:INVISIBLE card
- 2 SCO:r:MUDDLE cards
- 2 SCO:r:PIERCE3 cards
- 4 SCO:r:POISON cards

- 3 CRA:+1 cards
- 2 CRA:+1,IMMOBILIZE cards
- 2 CRA:+2 cards
- 2 CRA:+2,MUDDLE cards
- 1 CRA:-2 card
- 2 CRA:r:AIR cards
- 4 CRA:r:EARTH cards
- 2 CRA:r:PUSH2 cards

- 1 MIN:+0 card
- 2 MIN:+2 cards
- 2 MIN:+2,ICE cards
- 4 MIN:r:+1 cards
- 1 MIN:r:DISARM card
- 2 MIN:r:IMMOBILIZE cards
- 4 MIN:r:MUDDLE cards
- 3 MIN:r:PULL1 cards
- 1 MIN:r:STUN card

- 1 SUN:+0 card
- 2 SUN:+1 cards
- 1 SUN:+2 card
- 4 SUN:r:+1 cards
- 4 SUN:r:Heal1S cards
- 4 SUN:r:LIGHT cards
- 1 SUN:r:STUN card
- 2 SUN:r:Shield1S cards

- 3 QUA:+0,Refresh cards
- 2 QUA:+1 cards
- 2 QUA:+2 cards
- 4 QUA:r:+1 cards
- 3 QUA:r:MUDDLE cards
- 2 QUA:r:PIERCE3 cards
- 1 QUA:r:STUN card
- 1 QUA:r:TARGET card

- 1 SUM:+0 card
- 5 SUM:+1 cards
- 2 SUM:+2 cards
- 1 SUM:r:AIR card
- 1 SUM:r:DARK card
- 1 SUM:r:EARTH card
- 1 SUM:r:FIRE card
- 6 SUM:r:Heal1S cards
- 2 SUM:r:POISON cards
- 2 SUM:r:WOUND cards

- 2 NIG:+1 cards
- 2 NIG:+1,DARK cards
- 2 NIG:+1,INVISIBLE cards
- 2 NIG:-1,DARK cards
- 2 NIG:r:CURSE cards
- 2 NIG:r:Heal1S cards
- 6 NIG:r:MUDDLE cards
- 1 NIG:r:TARGET card

- 1 PLA:+0 card
- 4 PLA:+1 cards
- 3 PLA:+1,AIR cards
- 2 PLA:+2 cards
- 2 PLA:r:CURSE cards
- 2 PLA:r:IMMOBILIZE cards
- 3 PLA:r:POISON cards
- 2 PLA:r:STUN cards

- 2 BES:+1 cards
- 2 BES:+2,FIRE cards
- 1 BES:r:+1,DISARM card
- 2 BES:r:+2 cards
- 2 BES:r:Heal1S cards
- 2 BES:r:STUN cards
- 4 BES:r:WOUND cards

- 1 SOO:+0,STUN card
- 1 SOO:+1,DISARM card
- 1 SOO:+1,IMMOBILIZE card
- 1 SOO:+2,CURSE card
- 1 SOO:+2,POISON card
- 1 SOO:+2,WOUND card
- 1 SOO:+3,MUDDLE card
- 2 SOO:+4 cards
- 3 SOO:r:+1 cards
- 4 SOO:r:CURSE cards

- 1 DOO:+0,STUN card
- 6 DOO:+1 cards
- 1 DOO:+1,IMMOBILIZE card
- 1 DOO:+1,POISON card
- 1 DOO:+1,WOUND card
- 1 DOO:+2,MUDDLE card
- 4 DOO:r:+1 cards
- 2 DOO:r:TARGET cards

- 1 SAW:+0,Refresh card
- 2 SAW:+1,IMMOBILIZE cards
- 2 SAW:+2 cards
- 2 SAW:r:+2 cards
- 2 SAW:r:Heal3S cards
- 1 SAW:r:STUN card
- 4 SAW:r:WOUND cards

- 4 ELE:+0,AIR cards
- 4 ELE:+0,EARTH cards
- 4 ELE:+0,FIRE cards
- 4 ELE:+0,ICE cards
- 1 ELE:+0,STUN card
- 1 ELE:+0,TARGET card
- 1 ELE:+1 card
- 2 ELE:+1,PUSH1 cards
- 1 ELE:+1,WOUND card
- 2 ELE:+2 cards

- 3 BEA:+1 cards
- 2 BEA:+1,IMMOBILIZE cards
- 2 BEA:+1,WOUND cards
- 2 BEA:+2 cards
- 2 BEA:r:EARTH cards
- 6 BEA:r:Heal1S cards

- 2 BLA:+1 cards
- 1 BLA:+1,AIR card
- 1 BLA:+1,DARK card
- 1 BLA:+1,EARTH card
- 1 BLA:+1,LIGHT card
- 2 BLA:+1,POISON cards
- 2 BLA:+1,WOUND cards
- 1 BLA:+2,MUDDLE card
- 4 BLA:r:Heal1S cards

- 2 DIV:+1 cards
- 1 DIV:+1,Heal2A card
- 1 DIV:+1,Shield1A card
- 1 DIV:+2,CURSE card
- 1 DIV:+2,DARK card
- 1 DIV:+2,LIGHT card
- 1 DIV:+2,REGENERATE card
- 1 DIV:+3,MUDDLE card
- 2 DIV:+3,Shield1S cards
- 2 DIV:r:CURSE cards
- 2 DIV:r:Heal1S cards

"r" indicates a Rolling Modifier. "S" (on Shield and Heal cards) means "Self", while "A" means "Ally".

Comment: Thanks for adding the class specific counts too! Now I can verify as I go.

Answer (score 2):

## Gloomhaven comes with 145 non-class specific Attack Modifier Cards.

These include:

- *(100 cards)* Five `Standard Attack Modifier Decks`.

  - Each is composed of 20 cards. *(Source: Page 5, [Gloomhaven Rulebook](https://online.flippingbook.com/view/598058/5/))*
  - Four of them are for player characters (labeled 1-4).
  - One is the monster deck (labeled "m").
- *(10 cards)* Ten Bless cards.

  - These get shuffled into Standard Attack Modifier Decks due to a variety of effects.
- *(20 cards)* Twenty Curse cards.

  - These are technically two decks as of the [R1 Errata](https://online.flippingbook.com/view/598058/56/) -- one 10 card deck for cursing players, and one 10 card deck for cursing monsters.
- *(15 cards)* Fifteen -1 cards.

  - These are inserted into Standard Attack Modifier Decks when equipping items that introduce them as a penalty.